# Showing a set is closed or not in the space of real continuous function

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=\{F\in C([0,1]\times[0,1]) : F(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)\}$ for some continuous functions $f,g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$

Is $A$ closed in the space $C([0,1]\times[0,1])$ of real continuous functions with the supremum metric $\rho$?

I've been trying to prove the set $A$ is closed by taking convergent sequences but I don't know how to conclude the limit function is in $A$. Maybe there is a clever way of proving it, or maybe $A$ is closed.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: sorry, I meant maybe $A$ is not closed.

Comment: There's an equation, something like $F(?)=F(?)$ or $F(?)+F(?)=F(?)+F(?)$ or something, such that $F$ is in $A$ if and only if $F$ satisfies that equation...

Comment: F has to be of the form $F(x,y)=f(x)+f(y)$, for some continuous functions $f,g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ that is all I have

Comment: Well I'm not going to do the problem for you... Ok. Suppose that $F(x,y) = f(x) + g(y)$. What can you say about the two quantities $F(x,y) - F(0,y)$ and $F(x,0) - F(0,0)$?